# perl how to do string alignment in perl

Tags: string, perl

if I have two different strings like:

```
my $a = "garfieldaagt";
my $b = "field";
```

and I need to align them like

```
garfieldaagt
   field
```

to compare them, how could I do this?

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Add `homework` tag if it's homework.

Comment: Is your question how to right-align text or how to align the particular parts of two words that matches? E.g. if it was `garfield` vs `fields` instead.

Comment: what do you want to see if `$b` is not a substring of `$a`?. I.e. if `$b = "lkjfb"`.

Comment: It's not clear for all us why in order to compare strings you want such a strange task as align them. Can you elaborate? Is this production code, your hobby or homework? You can ask to help with homework on stackoverflow, it's not forbidden, but you must explicitly say so by using tags. Also, you will get different answers depending on whether it's homework or not.

Comment: Don't use `$a` and `$b` beyond a sorting subroutine.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [index](http://p3rl.org/index) function to search for a string wihtin a string and then use the [`x` repetition operator](http://p3rl.org/op#Multiplicative-Operators) to align your substring to the position where it was found in the longer string.

```
$a = "garfield";
$b = "field";
print $a,"\n";
print " " x index($a,$b) ,$b,"\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare visually, see the other answer. If you want to compare programmatically, a few options are possible.

1. You can use negative indices in strings and compare character-wise.
2. You can use [`substr`](http://p3rl.org/substr) and compare smaller string with a substring of larger one
3. You can use positive indices but add length difference to the [index](http://p3rl.org/index) in the larger string

Finally, if you want to pad the strings to the same length with spaces, you can use [`sprintf`](http://p3rl.org/sprintf) in the same fashion as [`printf`](http://p3rl.org/printf).

The second option is indeed what a programmer could write in production code:

```
my $x = "foobar";
my $y = "bar";

if ($y eq substr $x, -length($y))
{
    print "$y is a suffix of $x\n";
}
```

Regex or a full substring search is an overkill here.

Comment: I like your second option could you give a example please

Comment: I added the example. I hope it's not your homework because providing full answer to one's homework is not welcome here.

Comment: Oh I provided the answer to your original question of garfield vs field. In a more general setting of garfieldjdkfdjf vs garfield you should use `index` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`printf`](http://p3rl.org/printf) to print those strings with alignement :

```
printf "%8s\n%8s", $a, $b;
```

The number 8 here specifies how many characters are used for printing the strings, including whitespaces if needed.

Comment: That answers some other question, rather than the question that was asked here  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an X-Y problem. I think this question is more about determining whether string B is contained inside string A.

While a [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)/[`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) combo is tempting to use, regular expressions are better-suited for this requirement:

```
my $stringA = 'garfieldaagt';
my $stringB = 'field';

print "'$stringB' contained in '$stringA'\n" if $stringA =~ /$stringB/;
# 'field' contained in 'garfieldaagt'
```

Using regexes will also address more complicated needs like case-insensitive matching.

See [`perldoc perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) for a quick introduction.

Comment: Perhaps that should be `/\Q$stringB\E/`

Comment: case-insensitive matching can in case of substr/index can be easily achieved with `lc`. The 'index' approach is harder to write and maintain, but it's faster so it depends.

Comment: `lc` won't work correctly in certain Unicode cases for ci-matching.

Comment: @TLP : I avoided `\Q...\E` for sake of clarity and simplicity, but yes it is better to `quotemeta` the string.

Comment: @nponeccop : the Perl regex engine is highly optimized. It is difficult to say which approach would be faster without a benchmark over different test cases

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming is the way to do it, you will get:

Garfield

Garied

to

Garfield

Gar-ie-d

This is an alignment. Any other thing can be prefix search, substrings search or what you have.

It is done comparing Garfield x Garied in the form of a matrix and find the longest and cheaper path from the first letter matching to the last, penalizing gaps.

If you wieght less common letters with higher score, the alignments may be better. But not necessary in the case of natural languages (english, spanish).

Regards

Comment: don't understand how this answers the question?